# Applescript activate closed window

Tags: macos, applescript

how can I activate an application and make it open the "standard" window as if I would have clicked on the dock icon with applescript?

E.g. I am in iTunes, close the window with command-w open another application and then I click on the iTunes dock icon and iTunes becomes the frontmost application and opens up it's "standard" iTunes window.

When I want to simulate that with applescript I type:

```
tell application iTunes to activate
```

What happens then is, that iTunes becomes the frontmost application, but the "standard" window (in that case the iTunes window) isn't being opened.

Does anyone know about a way to open the "standard" window with a general approach for any application?

Thanks b00tsy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a long time I found out that what I expect to happen with

```
tell application "anyApplication" activate
```

actually happens with

```
tell application "anyApplication" reopen
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no true, single way to show a "standard" window. It is up to the developer of each application to decide how a window is to be created and shown. For example, here is iTunes and Microsoft Word 2008...

```
tell application "iTunes"
   activate
   set theBrowser to browser window 1
   set visible of theBrowser to true
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
   set newDocument to make new document
end tell
```

In iTunes, there are three "standard" windows—browser, EQ, and playlist—and browser and EQ *always* exist. But in Microsoft Word, however, we have to make a new document, which is as close to a "standard" as it gets. *Most* applications will work the same way Word does, but it isn't a guarantee and you will have to look at the Dictionary for a given application to see how it handles windows (although iTunes does have a `window` class to throw everyone off, but that's Applescript for ya...).

One more thing to note...in most cases, once a window is closed, the only way to reopen it is to open the file that populated the window you just created or simply create a new one. iTunes is rare in its implementation.

Comment: So I guess the application developer chooses whithin his/her app what to do when the app becomes unhidden again, and implements that behavior in a certain method which will be called then...

Comment: Exactly. Applescript's wonkiness comes more from individual developers' implementation and a lack of guidance from Apple than anything else.